# Play Json - Conflict when deserialize model

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I met an strange issue in a unit test about serialization / deserializable of case class in JSON. I'm using `play-json (2.5.10)` and I defined a model for my events :

```
case class BFFEvent
  (
    startTime: Long,
    endTime: Long,
    eventType: BFFEventType.Value, // just an enum 
    payload: Option[Payload]
  )

  object BFFEvent {
    implicit val BFFEventFormat = Json.format[BFFEvent]
  }
```

`Payload` is an ADT with many sub-types but I only put conflicted case classes  :

```
sealed trait Payload

case class UserFlag
  (
    flag: Option[BFFEventFlag],
    freeText: Option[String],
    source: Option[BFFEventSource],
    timestamp : Option[Timestamp]
  ) extends Payload

case class CommunicationMode(mode: Int) extends Payload


implicit val payloadReads = {
    val userFlag = Json.reads[UserFlag]
    val communicationMode = Json.reads[CommunicationMode]

      __.read[UserFlag](userFlag).map(x => x: Payload) |
      __.read[CommunicationMode](communicationMode).map(x => x: Payload)

  }

  implicit val payloadWrites = Writes[Payload] {
    case userFlag: UserFlag => Json.writes[UserFlag].writes(userFlag)
    case communicationMode: CommunicationMode => Json.writes[CommunicationMode].writes(communicationMode)
  }
```

In a unit test, I check if I can read/write a JSON of my payload model :

```
val communicationMode = BFFEvent(0, 0, BFFEventType.COMMUNICATIONMODE, Some(CommunicationMode(0)))

it should "serialize and deserialize a CommunicationMode" in {
    val validatedJSON = Json.toJson(communicationMode).validate[BFFEvent]
    validatedJSON should be(JsSuccess(communicationMode))
  }
```

Test Output :

```
BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(CommunicationMode(0)))
JsSuccess(BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(UserFlag(None,None,None,None))),)

JsSuccess(BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(UserFlag(None,None,None,None))),) was not equal to JsSuccess(BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(CommunicationMode(0))),)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.bioserenity.bff.test.TEST_BFF_MODELS_SERIALIAZER$$anonfun$1 at (TEST_BFF_MODELS_SERIALIAZER.scala:81)
Expected :JsSuccess(BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(CommunicationMode(0))),)
Actual   :JsSuccess(BFFEvent(0,0,COMMUNICATIONMODE,Some(UserFlag(None,None,None,None))),)
```

While the input for the json conversion is a `BFFEvent` with a `CommunicationMode` payload, it translated in a `UserFlag`. I think the issue comes from the order of match in the `payloadReads` function but changing the order of match cases creates another conflits so if anyone met this issue before, can he provides me a tip to solve it or better, a solution ?